# Join data from 3 tables

Tags: postgresql

```
table_1
id  customer_id
---------------
1           1
2           2
3           1
4           1
5           3
6           4

table_2
id  id_table1       device_mac
-------------------------------------
1       1           aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
2       1           11:22:33:44:55:66
3       2           1a:2a:3a:4a:5a:6a
4       3           2b:3b:4b:5b:6b:7b
5       4           3c:4c:5c:6c:7c:8c
6       2           4d:5d:6d:7d:8d:9d


table_3
id      device_mac          device_name
--------------------------------------- 
1   aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff           loc1
2   11:22:33:44:55:66           loc2
3   1a:2a:3a:4a:5a:6a           loc3
4   2b:3b:4b:5b:6b:7b           loc4
5   3c:4c:5c:6c:7c:8c           loc5
6   4d:5d:6d:7d:8d:9d           loc6
```

I have a requirement where I need to get the below details by customer_id using python and postgres db.

ex: get details with customer_id = 1

```
table1_id       count(table_2)                  device_names
1                       2                       [loc1, loc2]
3                       1                       [loc4]
4                       1                       [loc5]
```

I tried with individual queries using python:

```
select id from table_1 where customer_id=1;
for t1_id from ids above table_1 data:
  select * from table_2 where table_id=t1_id
  for t2_data from ids above table2_data:
     select * from table_3 where device_mac = t2_data.device_mac
     # generate expected rows
```

Can I just do this in a signle query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and aggregate:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       COUNT(*) count,
       STRING_AGG(t3.device_name, ',' ORDER BY t3.device_name) device_names
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.id_table1 = t1.id
INNER JOIN table_3 t3 ON t3.device_mac = t2.device_mac
WHERE t1.customer_id = 1
GROUP BY t1.id
```

If you are getting duplicate `device_name`s you may use `DISTINCT`:

```
STRING_AGG(DISTINCT t3.device_name, ',' ORDER BY t3.device_name) device_names
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bc970c97c9d407b99a3af1f55922efa7).
Results:

| id | count | device_names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | loc1,loc2 |
| 3 | 1 | loc4 |
| 4 | 1 | loc5 |

Comment: LEFT JOIN can be used to include null values in device_names